# Sketch the set of complex numbers

Tags: complex-numbers

$$S=\{z ∈ C : |z + \frac{13i}{(3-2i)}| < 2 ∧ -\frac{2π}{3} ≤ Arg(7z) ≤ -\frac{π}{6}\}$$

I multiplied $\frac{13i}{(3-2i)}$ by $3+2i$, so that's what i got
$$S=\{z ∈ C : |z + (-2+3i)| < 2 ∧ -\frac{2π}{3} ≤ Arg(7z) ≤ -\frac{π}{6}\}$$
but I don't understand what's next. We know that $z$ is complex number, it means that $z = x + iy$, but what can we do with it?
[image: here]

Comment: I think that, at some point, you need to start translating the algebra into geometry. You do, after all, need a geometric answer at the end. Why not start now? What is the geometric interpretation of each of the two conditions you have there?

Comment: **Hint** $\{z\mid |z-a|<b\}$ is the open ball of center $a$ and radius $b$. Moreover, $\arg(7z)=\arg(z)$...

Comment: @Surb, I think I understood your hint, but I didn't get the logic behind it. Can you explain, please, why arg(7)=arg()

Comment: @AndriiDovhun I think you should look into the geometry of that statement. What does it say about points in the plane and angles?

Comment: Let $~x + iy~ = z,~$ and let $~\displaystyle r = |z| = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}.$  Then Arg$(z)~$ is the unique angle $~\theta,~$ within a modulus of $~(2\pi),~$ such that $$\cos(\theta) = \frac{x}{r}, ~\sin(\theta) = \frac{y}{r}.$$  Now, let $~w = 7z = 7x + i7y.~$  Let $~R~$ denote $~|w| \implies R = 7r.~$  Then, Arg$(w)~$ is the unique angle $~\alpha,~$ within a modulus of $~2\pi,~$ such that $$\cos(\alpha) = \frac{7x}{R}, ~\sin(\alpha) = \frac{7y}{R}.$$  So, $$\cos(\alpha) = \cos(\theta), ~\sin(\alpha) = \sin(\theta) \implies \alpha = \theta.$$

Comment: @user376343: Obviously, in the context of the exercise, $\arg(z)\in [-\pi,\pi)$ and thus, $\arg(7)=0...$ ;-)

Comment: @Surb I wrongly added your name instead of OP. I wanted explain them that you're right. My apologies.